# Auto generate C# interfaces (with function prototypes) from XSD?

Tags: c#, interface, methods, xsd, code-generation

I know how to define classes/data-structures in XSD format and auto-generate equivalent C# classes (with either xsd.exe or the more elaborated xsd2code.exe).

I would like to define interface classes with methods that utilize the above defined data-structures. The goal is to create some process-to-process (on the same machine) communication protocol with strong-typed classes and interfaces.

I have a big salad in my head, combined from XSD, WSDL, SOAP, REST and more.. which technology should I use?

10x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I ended up using: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/codegen/XSLCodeGen.aspx

Answer (score 1):

XSD is used to define **data types**, not **interfaces** or protocols. I would go for mixing `WSDL` and `XSD`. I mean, you create a WSDL that defines interfaces and methods, then bind the arguments for those methods to types defined in an XSD, either internal or external to the WSDL.

[Samples here](http://logbus-ng.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/logbus-ng/tags/logbus-sharp-2.3.42/It.Unina.Dis.Logbus/Schemas/). As you can see, `logbus-management.wsdl` not only includes an XSD on its own, but also strongly refers the `filter` namespace from `logbus-filters.xsd`.

From that WSDL, you can use, in my case `wsdl /serverInterfaces logbus-management.wsdl logbus-filters.xsd` and get both the C# `interface`s and all the data types into one C# source code file. If you also generate a proxy via Visual Studio, you can get your SOAP. You might need a web service (ie. ASP.NET, possibly in `serverless mode`) but I'm not sure if you can run SOAP with remoting (you should) or use WCF.

## Follow-up

You now need to use `Remoting` to let process communicate. [Here](http://www.beansoftware.com/net-tutorials/net-remoting-tutorial.aspx) I found a tutorial. Your **skeleton** code should look like:

```
using System;
 
namespace addsubs
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Class1.
    /// </summary>
    public class addsubs : MarshalByRefObject, IMultiplier //what you compiled from WSDL
    {
        public int product;
        public int multiply(int a, int b)
        {
            product = a * b;
            return product;
        }
    }
}
```

Both application must *share* the `IMultiplier` interface (or whatever), and then, **when you get a reference** to your skeleton object (via a **local proxy** that .NET is supposed to create for you), **cast it to `IMultiplier`**

(I have no direct experience with .NET Remoting).

Comment: Oops.. (don't press ENTER in comments)
That was my basic thinking - define data structs in XSD and the interfaces in WSDL (I didn't realize I can define the data structs already inside WSDL as well).

The thing that somewhat confuses me is that each generated interface method has the [WebMethod] attribute attached to it.
I don't intend to use it with a web-service (at least not that I can think of in the near future) - I need it for communicating between processes on the same machine.

That's the thing that is foggy for me - can I use the WSDL generated classes just as regulare C# interfaces?

Comment: The WebServiceAttribute **enables** the method to be invoked via SOAP/WSDL (Web Service), but doesn't **limit** to that. As an interface, its methods can be invoked programmatically from other code. In order to concretely use the WebServiceBAttribute you **must** also inherit from WebService class, and not only implement the interface. Removing the attribute has no effect. What you have to do now is to let process communicate each other, like with CORBA (with which I have Java experience). I would suggest you Remoting, but I have no experience

Comment: Well, you've been of great help. Thank you!